# Script with Connect-AzAccount in Visual Studio Code: "Let's try something else"

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a script that does

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $myTenantId
```

When I run the script in Visual Studio Code, it pops up a dialog that lets me select the account I am interested in.
But, when I select my account it pops up a dialog with

[image]

I tried running it directly in the PowerShell Terminal and got the same results.

So, I tried doing

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Tenant $myTenantId
```

Again, while running the script, I get the same results at the `Connect-AzAccount` step.
HOWEVER, when I run these directly in the PowerShell Terminal it works. *(Grrr!!!)*

What needs to be done to get this to work?

**NOTES**:

- This code works for other tenants, but not with this new one.
- I get the same failure results if I try to do the command in a PowerShell window.
- If I run the original command in pwsh Terminal it pops open a browser and connect is successful, but I need it to work in PowerShell 5.1.
- I get the same successful results if I try to do the command in a pwsh window.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run the script with command `Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $myTenantId` from `VSCode` with multiple tenant ID's and Iam able to login without any issues.

[image]

[image]

- Try to clear the cache and try in the new / different browser.
- Try to run the same tenant in another system and check once.

May be the Tenant ID which you are trying to login does not exists or not configured with the current Subscription.

Check whether the tenant which you have selected exists in the subscription.

Before setting the Tenant ID with `Set-AzContext -Tenant $myTenantId` try to set the Subscription ID as suggested in the [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-azure-subscription-in-powershell).

- If you still face any issue it is advised to contact Azure Support team.